# Spring AOP with SPring MVC controllers not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

HI I am using the following annotation based config ,to wire up my aspect which looks on the spring controllers for logging and other cross cutting method calls.But it seems the code I am using is not getting invoked .

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan({"com.pumpkinsafari.api"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /** The Constant DD_MM_YYYY. */
    private static final String DD_MM_YYYY = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    /** The Constant DATE_FORMAT. */
    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(DD_MM_YYYY);

    /**
     * Instantiates a new web config.
     */
    public WebConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestControllerAspect controllerAspect(){
        return new RestControllerAspect();
    }

    // beans

    /**
     * Xstream marshaller.
     * 
     * @return the x stream marshaller
     */
    public XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller() {
        final XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        xStreamMarshaller.setAutodetectAnnotations(true);
        xStreamMarshaller.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[] { Principal.class, Customer.class, Role.class,
                Privilege.class, SocialUser.class, SearchRequest.class });
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addDefaultImplementation(java.sql.Timestamp.class, java.util.Date.class);

        return xStreamMarshaller;
    }

    /**
     * Marshalling http message converter.
     * 
     * @return the marshalling http message converter
     */
    public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter() {
        final MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
        final XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = xstreamMarshaller();
        marshallingHttpMessageConverter.setMarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);
        marshallingHttpMessageConverter.setUnmarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);

        return marshallingHttpMessageConverter;
    }

    // template

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
     * #configureMessageConverters(java.util.List)
     */
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        messageConverters.add(marshallingHttpMessageConverter());

        final ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        if (ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper", classLoader)) {
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            jackson2HttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            // Register date format for marshalling unmarshalling dates
            jackson2HttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            messageConverters.add(jackson2HttpMessageConverter);
        } else if (ClassUtils.isPresent("org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper", classLoader)) {
            MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter jacksonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
            jacksonHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().disable(
                    DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            // Register date format for marshalling unmarshalling dates
            jacksonHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            messageConverters.add(jacksonHttpMessageConverter);
        }

        super.configureMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    }

}
```

but my aspect  is not getting invoked ..The aspect class is as below

```
@Aspect
public class RestControllerAspect {

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
    public void controller() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void methodPointcut() {
        System.out.println("Invoked: ");
    }

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *)")
    public void requestMapping() {
        System.out.println("Invoked: ");
    }

    @Before("controller() && methodPointcut() && requestMapping()")
    public void aroundControllerMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Invoked: " + niceName(joinPoint));
    }

    @AfterReturning("controller() && methodPointcut() && requestMapping()")
    public void afterControllerMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Finished: " + niceName(joinPoint));
    }

    private String niceName(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        return joinPoint.getTarget().getClass() + "#" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "\n\targs:"
                + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs());
    }

}
```

Please HELP SOMEONE !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your `@Pointcut` definitions. For types instead of `within(@....` use  `@within(....`, for methods instead of `within(@....` use  `@annotation(....`

See [spring referene](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) regarding pointcuts for more info